# New MathJax features

Tags: discussion

I see that MathJax now shows red text in the preview window for markup, making editing and creating expressions much simpler.  Is this new??  If so, kudos to the devs.

UPDATE:
Finally got around to snipping the screen.  Note that before I completed the \$\LaTeX\$ macro, the preview screen shows it in red
[image]

Comment: Out of interest what browser are you using? I just tried using the latest Firefox and couldn't seem to spot anything different.

Comment: @PeterJ It was Chrome

Comment: Would you care to add a picture so we could see the difference? I didn't notice anything different either.

Comment: Going camping, so I'll be well of the grid.  I'll update wit screen shots next week

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this has worked for a long time like this for unknown TeX commands. There is a different case, when the command is known but for some reason something couldn't be rendered. It then looks like this:

$$\frac{5}$$

In any case, [nothing seems to have been changed recently](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/commits/master).